# Apache 2.4 install on 12.04 ends up with non-standard configuarion

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I've just done an install of Apache 2.4 following the steps outlined here: http://edin.no-ip.com/blog/hswong3i/apache-2-4-php5-4-pdo-oci-ubuntu-12-04-howto (except for the Oracle specific stuff).

However, I've now ended up with Apache using the config in /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf, not /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as I'm used to.

httpd.conf doesn't seem to have been setup to use sites-available and mods-available and all that goodness.

What's the best solution for this?  Is there something I can tweak quickly to get it to work as expected, or is 2.4 not expected to work that way in 12.04?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try symlinking `/usr/local/conf/apache2/conf` to point at `/etc/apache2`. You might need a symlink from `httpd.conf` to `apache2.conf` too.

Comment: Hmm, but if I symlink like that my sites-available, etc directories are gone, no?  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, how would they be gone? The symlink merely makes /etc/apache2 appear as if it is ALSO at /usr/local/conf/apache2/conf. Of course, if sites-available is a relative symlink pointing outside /etc/apache2, it would probably break. But I don't think it is.